# Git color ui uses green for both deletions and insertions

Tags: git, colors

When enabling git color ui, the only color used is green. So in git diff I get green for both deletions and insertions. The same goes for git status where untracked files and unstaged files show as green. Color ui is so useful, but this bug practically makes it worthless.

If anyone can help me fix it I would be grateful.

Comment: Have you got any color entries in your .git/config file?

Comment: No, and this happens to all my cloned repos.